# Title of Segmented Control does not fit, overlaps

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

In my segmented control, sometimes the title is wider than fits its segment. How can I make it truncate?

Let's say the title of segment 1 is `Text overlaps` and segment 2 is named `ok`.

How I want it to look:

```
  [Text ov...|   ok   ]
```

What it looks like:

```
 T[ext overla|ps  ok   ]
```

What I tried:

- Setting the width of the segment programmatically [`setWidth:forSegment`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW16). Still overlapping, not truncating.
- Studying the properties of [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Do I have to truncate it myself, before setting the title of the segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to truncate it yourself.

There is no public API for setting the truncation.  Even if you dig through the `UISegmentedControl`'s private view hierarchy, find the labels, and set `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`, it won't truncate the labels for you.  (I tried.)

**EDIT:** I got this to work.  It's not pretty, it might stop working in a future iOS release, and it might get you rejected from the App Store.

```
static void fixLineBreakMode(UIView *view)
{
    if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setLineBreakMode:)]) {
        [(id)view setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
        [view setFrame:CGRectInset([view.superview bounds], 6, 0)];
    } else {
        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
            fixLineBreakMode(subview);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    fixLineBreakMode(self.segmentedControl);
}
```

Comment: For what reasons would this get an app rejected?

Comment: You'd be accessing a private view hierarchy.  I don't know if they would reject you for that.  I'm just pointing out the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge when I needed to populate a segmented control with x number of segments. Some titles were overhanging. I have tried to truncate the titles in middle if they were too long. I did something like:

```
    NSString *s = @"This title is too long to fit";
NSMutableString *mS = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
int len = [s length];
if (len > 10) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unichar ch = [s characterAtIndex:i];
        if(i > 3 && i < 6){
            [mS appendString:@"."];
        } else  {
            [mS appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", ch]];
        }
    }
}
```

This is just to give you some idea. You can limit the number of dots in the middle, just count the number of dots appended and stop adding when e.g. it reaches 3. When you have the truncated string you can use that to set a segment title. The same logic for head, tail truncating.